# telnet to port 25 from AS400

Tags: telnet, ibm-midrange

I want to very SMTP connectivity from an AS400 in a VM to a mailserver on port 25

The native telnet command on the as400 does not seem to support a port specification.

Any ideas how to telnet from as400 to port 25 on my mailserver?

I can ping the mailserver from the as400

I can telnet in from other boxes (non as400)

Answer (score 6):

I just tried this on an i5/OS V5R4:

```
TELNET RMTSYS(hostname) ASCOPRMOD(*VT100) PORT(25)
```

I also found [an IBM manual about telnet support in V5R2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/rzaiw/rzaiw.pdf) that suggests you can also specify a port in older versions.

Comment: telnet rmtsys(host) port(25) was just what I was looking for Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Type "TELNET" on the command line, press F4, fill out the remote system name, press F10, page down, page down, locate "Port" field.  Change it from "*DFT" to "25".  Press Enter.

When done, press F9 to get the corresponding command line invocation.